# Add column index to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
          Sim_1     Sim_2     Sim_3          
2016   1.063708  1.008885  1.028539  
2017   1.114644  0.994331  1.043218
```

In order to append it to another, two-indexed dataframe, I'd like to add a new level below the existing column names, such that the dataframe will have following structure

```
SIMULATION  Sim_1     Sim_2     Sim_3   
IDX          LR        LR        LR
2016      1.063708  1.008885  1.028539  
2017      1.114644  0.994331  1.043218
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, 
                                       ['LR'] * len(df.columns)], 
                                       names=('SIMULATION','IDX'))
print (df)
SIMULATION     Sim_1     Sim_2     Sim_3
IDX               LR        LR        LR
2016        1.063708  1.008885  1.028539
2017        1.114644  0.994331  1.043218
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['LR']], names=['SIMULATION', 'IDX'])
>>> df
SIMULATION     Sim_1     Sim_2     Sim_3
IDX               LR        LR        LR
2016        1.063708  1.008885  1.028539
2017        1.114644  0.994331  1.043218
```